Determine for the numbers $r \in \{-1,2,6,\frac{4}{5}\}$ the set of primenumbers $p$, such that r is a suqare in the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
Determine for the numbers $r \in \{-1,2,6,\frac{4}{5}\}$ the set of primenumbers $p$, such that r is a suqare in the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
I want to use the following Theorem for that.
Theorem:
Let $p$ be odd prime. The map $\Phi_p{:\mathbb{Q}}_p^{\times}/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times^{}2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $up^n \mapsto (\mu((\frac{u}{p})),n \mod 2)$ is a isomorphism.
Where $\mu (-1)=\overline{1}$, $\mu(1)=\overline{0}$.
My Approach:
If $\Phi_p(r)=(0,0)$, then r is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
Suppose I can write $r$ as $up^n$.
Then r is a square if n \equiv 0 \mod 2 and the Legendre-Symbol $(\frac{u}{p})=1$.
For the Legendre-Symbol $(\frac{u}{p})$ to be $1$ means that $x^2 \equiv u \mod p$ has a solution ($\neq 0$).
Case $r=-1$:
I can write $-1$ as $p^0\cdot (-1)$ for $p \in \mathbb{P}$.
So 0 $\equiv 0 \mod 2$ is always statisfied.
For the Legendre-Symbol $(\frac{-1}{p})$ I know the following formula $(\frac{-1}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$. Thus $(\frac{-1}{p})=1$ if $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$.
Case r=2:
For $p=2, r=2^1 \cdot 1$, thus can't be a square.
Let $p >2$, then $r = p^0 \cdot 2$ and we need to calculate $(\frac{2}{p})$ for $p>2$. Here we know that $(\frac{2}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}$. This means that $(\frac{2}{p})=1$ if $p =+1$ or $-1 \mod 8$.
I assume that the Case r=6 will be similar to the above. But for $r=\frac{4}{5}$, I do not know how to approach this. My Problem is that I do not know the decomposition of $\frac{4}{5}$ into $p^n u$.
Also is my solution for $r=-1$ and $r=2$ correct?

$4/5=(2/5)^2\times 5$

Your approaches for $r=-1$ and $r=2$ are correct; while a similar approach will work for $r=6$, it will likely take a little more work to determine the primes $p$ for which $\left(\frac{6}{p}\right) = 1$.
For $\frac{4}{5}$, we can write it as $2^25^{-1}$, so for example when $p=5$ you have $n=-1$ and $u=4$. For primes that are not $5$, note that you will have $n=2$ and $u=\frac{1}{5}$ for $p=2$ and $n=0$ and $u=\frac{4}{5}$ otherwise. To handle these, note that $5$ will be invertible mod $p$ whenever $p\neq 5$ so $\frac{1}{5}$ really means whatever class is the multiplicative inverse of $5\bmod p$. I will also note that (as is evident in your theorem statement), the criterion of $n\equiv 0\bmod 2$ and $\left(\frac{u}{p}\right) = 1$ only works for odd $p$. To determine whether $r$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ requires a different criterion on $u$.
Below I will write some more details in spoiler.
Case $r=6$:

 For $p=2$ and $p=3$ we have $n=1$ so $6$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ or $\mathbb{Q}_3$. For other $p$, we have $n=0$ and $u=6$ so it suffices to determine when $\left(\frac{6}{p}\right)=1$. To that end, we use the splitting of Legendre symbols to note that $\left(\frac{6}{p}\right)=1$ if and only if $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{3}{p}\right)$. Now we consider further cases.
 

 First when $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = 1$, we must have $p\equiv \pm1 \bmod 8$ for $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = 1$. For $3$ we use Quadratic Reciprocity to say that either
 
$p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ and $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=1$ or
 
$p\equiv 3\bmod 4$ and $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=-1$.
 
 The first case corresponds to $p\equiv 1\bmod 12$ and the second to $p\equiv 11 \bmod 12$. Combining these with the conditions on $2$ yields $p\equiv \pm1 \bmod 24$.
 

 Now when $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = -1$, we must have $p\equiv \pm3 \bmod 8$ for $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = -1$. For $3$ we use Quadratic Reciprocity to say that either
 
$p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ and $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right) = -1$ or
 
$p\equiv 3\bmod 4$ and $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right) = 1$.
 
 The first case corresponds to $p\equiv 5\bmod 12$ and the second to $p\equiv 7 \bmod 12$. Combining these with the conditions on $2$ yields $p\equiv \pm5 \bmod 24$.

Case $r = \frac{4}{5}$:

 For $p=5$ we have $n=-1$ so $\frac{4}{5}$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}_5$. For $p=2$ we have $n=2$ and $u=\frac{1}{5} \equiv 5 \bmod 8$, so $\frac{4}{5}$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ either. For other $p$ we have $n=0$ so we need to determine when $\frac{4}{5}$ is a square mod $p$. We first must note that this is well-defined since $p\neq 5$, so $5$ is invertible mod $p$. Since $4$ is a square, we need only determine when $5^{-1}$ is a square mod $p$. We note that since $5\cdot 5^{-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$ and $1$ is a square, the splitting of Legendre symbols means that $\left(\frac{5^{-1}}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{5}{p}\right)$. We now use Quadratic Reciprocity to say that $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{p}{5}\right)$ so $p\equiv\pm1\bmod 5$.

